# how to query data from database postgres sql (using sequeilize ORM )into customize json format

Tags: node.js, api, sails.js, sequelize.js

How to query data with PostgreSQL into customized JSON format? For example: I need to retreive data from `tagParent` table and `tagsChild` table where `tagParentId` is a foreign key in `tagsChild` table.

```
"tagParentDetails":[
{
"id": 20,
"ParentName": "Parentone",
"TagChildDetails":[
    {"id": 1, "name": "Child1"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Child2"},
    {"id": 3, "name": "Child3"},
    {"id": 4, "name": "Child4"},
    ]
},
```

Comment: This would be fairly simple in Waterline, the ORM baked into Sails.
Have you replaced Waterline with Sequalize? Or are you using them both?

Comment: actually i am using sequalize orm, if i write one store procedure in postgres how i customize the result into certain json format.for eg repeated records in a row to an object .

Comment: Don't know the process for Sequalize sorry. I've added the tag to your question to hopefully attract someone who can answer